# Nest Subsections in the AppSettings App.Config Node

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, app-config

This question is inspired by and serves as an extension to the question found here: [sub appsettings in the appsetting node c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812008/sub-appsettings-in-the-appsetting-node-c-sharp)

My question is, is it possible to nest further nodes in the appSettings node in App.config in WPF and then access them accordingly?

Something like:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <UISettings>
            <add key="SomeUIKey" value="SomeUIValue" />
        </UISettings>
        <ProgramSettings>
            <add key="SomeProgramKey" value="SomeProgramValue" />
        </ProgramSettings>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

At the behest of Meta Stackoverflow I'd like to clarify that the accepted answer to the original question is, in my opinion, unsatisfactory as it provides a workaround instead of a solid answer to the question. What I'm looking to do is not specify further configSections but use appSettings in a way similar to a custom sectionGroup. Is this even possible?