# Sectioning App Settings

Tags: c#, xml, combobox, app-config

I am currently developing a WinForm for a friend.  It is a very small application, however it may require updating certain combo boxes with alternate information.
My friend isn't a developer.  I am putting all of the Combobox items in the appSettings file so that I can show her how to add items when it comes up.
My question is if there is a way to subsection the different entries in AppSettings.

Is there a way to format:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="cmbBox1.Item1" value="value 1_1" />
  <add key="cmbBox1.Item2" value="value 1_2" />
  <add key="cmbBox2.Item1" value="value 2_1" />
  <add key="cmbBox2.Item2" value="value 2_2" />
</appSettings>
```

Such as:

```
 <appSettings>
      <cmbBox1>
        <add key="Item1" value="value 1_1" />                        
        <add key="Item2" value="value 1_2" />
      </cmbBox1>
      <cmbBox2>
        <add key="Item1" value="value 2_1" />
        <add key="Item2" value="value 2_2" />
      </cmbBox2>
    </appSettings>
```

Is there a way to have a structure like this and to access with:

```
List<string> cmb1Items = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.cmbBox1.AllKeys.ToList();
List<string> cmb2Items = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.cmbBox2.AllKeys.ToList();
```

Rather than:

```
List<string> cmb1Items = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Contains("cmbBox1").ToList();
List<string> cmb2Items = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Contains("cmbBox2").ToList();
```

This is just for ease of reading through the XML and organization.
There will be many ComboBoxes and using the root keys can/will become very daunting

Comment: Create own separate .xml file. And freely build xml structure you want. Then in the code you can create class which represent all data. You can deserialize xml values in that class instance and use it in your application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sub appsettings in the appsetting node c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812008/sub-appsettings-in-the-appsetting-node-c-sharp)